# Angular 5 ngFor select options ngModel within form tags

Tags: angular

This is my html

```html
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(editBook)" #editBook="ngForm" [hidden]="success">
  <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let bookInstance of bookInstanceList; let i=index; trackBy: trackByBookList;">    
    <label for="'status'+i">Book Status</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="'status'+i" required [(ngModel)]="bookInstance.status" name="'status'+i">
      <option *ngFor="let stat of statusList" [ngValue]="stat">{{stat}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my statusList

```js
export class BookDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() book: any[];

  public statusList = ['Available', 'Not Available'];

  public bookInstanceList = [
    { "status": "Not Available" },
    { "status": "Available" }
}
```

Currently the values Bind accordingly which is great. However, the first option value for the first bookInstance shows "Available". But as you can see, the bookInstanceList first element is "Not Available". How can i get the option to show the value of "Not Available"?

Comment: For template driven form, there won't exist two field with same name property. Since your two `select` share the same name property, the first select's value will be overwritten by the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding index to name should be `name="status+ {{i}}"`

```
  <select class="form-control" id=" status+ {{i}}" required [(ngModel)]="bookInstance.status" name="status+ {{i}}">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stbeg7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)